# why functions are false in python?

Tags: python, boolean

I can't figure out why:

```
f = lambda x: x
In [8]: f is True
Out[8]: False

In [9]: not f is True
Out[9]: True

In [10]:  f is False
Out[10]: False

In [11]: f is True
Out[11]: False

In [12]: not f
Out[12]: False

In [13]: not f is True
Out[13]: True

In [14]: not f is False
Out[14]: True
```

ok. So until now we can imagine that is due to the use of "is" instead of "==". As shown here:

```
In [15]: 0.00000 is 0
Out[15]: False

In [16]: 0.00000 == 0
Out[16]: True
```

Ok. But why then if i do it on the function:

```
In [17]: not f == False
Out[17]: True

In [18]: not f == True
Out[18]: True

In [19]: f ==True
Out[19]: False

In [20]: f ==False
Out[20]: False

In [21]: f
Out[21]: <function __main__.<lambda>>
```

I was trying to explain it as due to "is" instead of "==" but examples 19 and 20 crushed my logic. Can someone explain?

Comment: Is this specific to functions? How do other values compare against True and False?

Comment: awww so stupid. forgot to compare the boolean value using bool(). of course . please delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`==` checks for equivelency ... `is` checks identity ... 
a function is a non-falsey value however it is not equivelent to True

```
def xyz():
   pass

if xyz:
   #this will trigger since a method is not a falsey value

xyz == True #No it is not equal to true
xyz == False #no it is not equal to false

xyz is True #no it certainly is not the same memory location as true
xyz is False #no it is also not the same memory location as false
```

Answer (score 5):

`is` tests for *object identity*. Comparing anything other than `True` with `is True` is always going to be false.

Your next set of tests test if `not (f == False)` or `not (f == True)`; again, boolean objects only test equal against themselves, so anything other than `False` will test as false when comparing with `== False`. `not False` then is true.

You want to use `bool()` instead to test if something is true or false:

```
>>> bool(f)
True
>>> bool(0)
False
```

Don't use equality testing to see if something is true or false.

Note that only numeric 0, empty containers and strings, and `False` is considered false  in Python. Everything else, by default, is considered true in a boolean context. Custom types can implement either the [`__nonzero__` method](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__) (when numeric) or the [`__len__` method](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__) (to implement a container) to alter that behaviour. Python 3 replaced `__nonzero__` with the [`__bool__` method](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__).

Functions do not have a `__nonzero__` or `__len__` method, so they are always considered true.

Comment: Your first statement says `True is True` always going to be `False`. Why? I'd expect it to be `True` and my interpreter concurs.

Comment: I know what you're saying, but taken literally, "Anything other than `True is True`" can be easily misread (to, e.g., mean that `False is False` would be false).

Comment: Ah. I either read it too fast or the first draft of the answer didn't have it. Either way, mea culpa. Thanks.

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim: *Anything other than [statement] is going to be false*.

Answer (score 2):

If you check the "truthyness" of a function, you will see it is True.

```
>>> f = lambda x: x
>>> bool(f)
True
```

You were simply comparing the function itself to `True` or `False` Which it would never be, since it is a function.

Answer (score 0):

Your own example shows that `f is False` is false so I'm confused by your title.

Why would you expect a function to evaluate as equal to either Boolean value? Wouldn't that be kind of weird behaviour?

Comment: if you forget some parenthesis.
`if char.isdigit and char in ['1','2']` vs `if char.isdigit() and char in ['1','2']`